# Is there anything else I can do to trouble not having a video out to my monitors?

Tags: display, motherboard, gpu, troubleshooting

I have just finished a new build; I am not receiving a signal from the pc to the monitor. I have done the troubleshooting steps below.

My gut says I have missed something during assembly or missed something during troubleshooting.

Any suggestions on where this issue might lie? Should I send this board back to MSI?

I'm looking forward to your feedback.

Build Specs

- CPU: i7-9700K
- Motherboard: MSI MPG Z390 Gaming Pro Carbon
- GPU: Nvidia 1050Ti
- PSU: Seasonic 550w Focus
- Storage: 2TB Hybrid Drive

Troubleshooting Steps taken:

1. Examined debug led. None are lit.
2. Replaced HDMI cable with a known working HDMI cable and made sure montor was on correct setting. Still no signal to monitor.
3. Examined GPU for power and connection. The board was powered and seated fully.
4. Removed GPU and ran video out from the motherboard.
5. Used other video out connections (DVI, Display Port)from the motherboard with GPU removed.
6. Removed and reseated RAM sticks.
7. Started build with only RAM in the DIMMA2 slot.
8. Reset CMOS by turning off the power supply and removing the battery for 1 minute

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to connect the auxiliary CPU power in the upper-left of the board.

Aside from that my next steps would be:

1. Remove the GPU
2. Remove the CMOS battery
3. Plug the HDMI cord into an onboard port and try starting the system
4. Check your BIOS setting to see if onboard or external GPU is selected in the preferences

If you cannot get a signal from the motherboard then it might be defective.